# Template class as function's return type mismatch

Tags: c++, abseil

```cpp
static absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame> ReadTextureFromFile() {
      ImageFrame image_frame(width, height);
      return image_frame;
}
```

Why return type is `ImageFrame` and not `absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame>`?

Comment: it's `absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame>`. It's it's okay, you may get the data `ImageFrame` or status code if failed.

Comment: You might want to read [Absil's document](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/status#returning-a-status-or-a-value)

Comment: The return type is `absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame>`. But, seemingly, the object of this type can be initialized by another object of type `ImageFrame` (possibly with a converting constructor).

Comment: This is yet another example of why programmers need to know what a monad is. /rant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a "syntactic sugar". The return type is `abseil::StatusOr<ImageFrame>`. `abseil::StatusOr<T>` allows you to return both `abseil::Status` and the type `T` from your function. When there is an error you can directly return the error status. On success, you return the object with type `T`.

So you could also write something like that:

```
static absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame> ReadTextureFromFile() {
      try {
          ImageFrame image_frame(width, height);
      }
      catch{
          return absl::AbortedError("Could not create image frame.");
      }
      return image_frame;
}
```

When you call this function, you need to check if everything went smooth.

```
auto image_frame_or = ReadTextureFromField();
ImageFrame image_frame;
if (image_frame_or.ok()){
    image_frame = image_frame_or.value();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The return type is `absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame>` as specified in the signature of the function.

But looking at the [definition of `absl::StatusOr`](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/status/statusor.h#L433), there is a converting constructor that moves an object of type `T` into a `absl::StatusOr<T>` so your code is executed as if you wrote

```
static absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame> ReadTextureFromFile() {
      ImageFrame image_frame(width, height);

      // Call absl::StatusOr(U&&)
      absl::StatusOr<ImageFrame> returnValue{ image_frame };
      return returnValue;
}
```